# re.findall generate unexpected extra spaces

Tags: python, regex

I constructed such a regex following an instrucion

```
#Create phone regex
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''( 
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?  # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?  # separator
    (\d{3})  # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.) # separator
    (\d{4})  # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

I tested it

```
In [91]: text 
Out[91]: '800-420-7240 415-863-9900 415-863-9950'
In [92]: phoneRegex.findall(text)
Out[92]: 
[('800-420-7240', '800', '-', '420', '-', '7240', '', '', ''),
 ('415-863-9900', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9900', '', '', ''),
 ('415-863-9950', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9950', '', '', '')]
```

There are three `None` at the end of each groups, especially the last one of `415-863-9950` which has no spaces.

How could the extra spaces are generated?

Comment: `''` is an empty string, not a `None`.

Comment: There are nine capturing groups in your regex, therefore there are nine groups in each result from `.findall()`.  If you don't want all those groups, change them to non-capturing groups - `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`. Or just remove the parentheses entirely, if they're not actually needed for anything.

Comment: Could you please transmit the comment to answer. @jasonharper

Comment: @Painter why do you need the last one? `(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  # extension` ? Removing this eliminates the unwanted empty values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **re.findall**(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are
>   returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the
>   pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the
>   pattern has more than one group. **Empty matches are included in the**
>   **result**.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

In your regex, you have an optional group. i.e:

```
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?
```

`?` implies this group is optional, and due to that, `findAll()` returns `None` for every non matching groups. You can of course mark the groups as non capturing by adding `?:` just before your group, but if you do that, you will not be able to capture values like: `800-420-7240 ext 1112 415-863-9900 415-863-9950` (as per the last group, which captures the `ext`). [correct me if I'm wrong with this last statement]

However, you can remove the the `None` values and return only the valid groups by using a small workaround.

```
import re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''( 
    (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?  # area code
    (\s|-|\.)?  # separator
    (\d{3})  # first 3 digits
    (\s|-|\.) # separator
    (\d{4})  # last 4 digits
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

matches = phoneRegex.findall('800-420-7240 ext 1112 415-863-9900 415-863-9950')
# matches = phoneRegex.findall('800-420-7240 415-863-9900 415-863-9950')

for i in matches:
    print filter(None, i)
```

This will give the output as:

```
('800-420-7240 ext 1112', '800', '-', '420', '-', '7240', ' ext 1112', 'ext', '1112')
('415-863-9900', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9900')
('415-863-9950', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9950')
```

Hope it helps!! Please feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Like jasenharper pointed out in the comments, the empty strings have their origin in the empty capture groups. The easiest way to get rid of them is cleaning up your list after applying the regex:

```
s = phoneRegex.findall(text)
s = [('800-420-7240', '800', '-', '420', '-', '7240', '', '', ''),
 ('415-863-9900', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9900', '', '', ''),
 ('415-863-9950', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9950', '', '', '')]

newS = []
for e in s:
    sl = list(filter(lambda x: x != "",e))
    newS.append(sl)
print(newS) # [['800-420-7240', '800', '-', '420', '-', '7240'], ['415-863-9900', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9900'], ['415-863-9950', '415', '-', '863', '-', '9950']]
```